# Has the recent update changed whats the most powerfull attack?

Tags: pokemon-go

This morning I noticed a lot of attacks have been adjusted.

Did this change whats the most powerfull attack speaking in dps?

Answer (score 0):

As it currently seems `Stone Edge` is the most powerful special attack speaking of DPS with a raw DPS of 32.26. 

`Pound` is the most powerful normal attack (12.96 DPS) and `Hyper Beam` and `Solar Beam` are the attacks with the highest damage attribute (120).

Maybe those changes help to let people do something useful even without Snorlax or Vaporeon.

*[Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_nO-IuAWZk3iAtFNDdeG7E_98XBC3DsGW0WPWkiQnuk/htmlview?sle=true#)*